# Localizing Cogs for discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a issue when it comes to localizing cogs (modules/addons) per each server.
Currently I am able to load a cog if the install command is given however it carries over to every other server the bot is on. How could I localize it so that each server has its own separate cogs loaded?

I have attempted several different ideas however none of them turned up any results  so I don't have any code I can really share.

I do understand I could make a checking system for this to work however I'm unsure of how I can do this without being able to say which server has what cogs loaded.

I'm sorry this question may not be the most pretty looking question around, but this is as much as I am able to really provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.  Loading a cog modifies the `Client`/`Bot` object: adding `Command` objects, event callbacks, etc.  Since you only have a single `Bot` or `Client` that is logged in on the bot account at a time, that instance is shared by all the servers.

You have a few options:

1. Subclass `Bot` to have an attribute that records a mapping between servers and cogs.  Change the Cogs `setup` function to modify this mapping, and add an `__unload` method that also modifies it.  In your cog code, check that mapping before doing anything.
2. Register multiple bot accounts, one for each server, and load cogs freely.
3. If you're using the rewrite branch *and your cog is only commands*, you can define a `__local_check` method of the cog that will determine if a command can be run or not using a `Context` object.  [See an example here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#cog-changes).  The async branch only lets you write global checks.  If there are any events in your cog, you will need to add checks to them manually, as they don't generate `Context` objects.